# Rails 3 cookies undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I have a Rails 3 blog. I want every Post to have a "Like" button. Clicking on it will save this action to the database and store to cookies on the user who has just liked the Post (for disallowing same action again).

I wrote a simple action to do this:

```
def like
  render :nothing => true

  id = params[:post_id]
  cookies.permanent[:like_history] ||= []

  unless cookies.permanent[:like_history].include? id
    cookies.permanent[:like_history] << id

    @post = Post.find(id)
    @post.update_column(:likes, @post.likes + 1)
  end
end
```

But I'm getting `NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass)` when I try to log things. It points to this line: `cookies.permanent[:like_history] ||= []` as if cookies.permanent isn't an array.

Am I doing something wrong with cookies here?

Comment: `cookies.permanent[:test] = 'test'` works in other places at your app, e.g. in `ApplicationController`?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out, the ||= operator counts as "reading" by rails standards, which actually makes sense. You can't "read" with `cookies.permanent[:symbol]`, that's for writing, you read with `cookies[:symbol]`. So I modified that line to read:

`cookies.permanent[:like_history] = "" unless defined? cookies[:like_history]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have something stored in `cookies.permanent[:like_history]` which is not an `Array`. So make it `nil` or `covert to array` using `to_a` and try your code.

```
def like
  render :nothing => true
  cookies.permanent[:like_history] = nil #or cookies.permanent[:like_history] = cookies.permanent[:like_history].to_a 

  id = params[:post_id]
  cookies.permanent[:like_history] ||= []

  unless cookies.permanent[:like_history].include? id
    cookies.permanent[:like_history] << id

    @post = Post.find(id)
    @post.update_column(:likes, @post.likes + 1)
  end
end
```

Once it works remove that line you added.